# Having a problem with boolean logic loop with password checker

Tags: java, variables

I'm trying to create a Java program that checks to see if an input password has at least three lowercase letters, 2 uppercase letters, and 1 digit. This is what I have so far:

```
Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean valid= false;
    String password;
    do{

    System.out.print("Enter a password that contains at least 2 uppercase letters, three lowercase letters, and at least 1 digit: ");
    password = inputDevice.nextLine();
    boolean Upper;
    boolean Lower;
    boolean Digit;
    int UpperCount=0;
    int LowerCount=0;
    int DigitCount=0;
    for(int i=0; i<password.length(); i++){
        if (Character.isUpperCase(password.charAt(i)));
            UpperCount++;}
        if (UpperCount<2)
            Upper=false;
        else
            Upper=true;
    for(int i=0; i<password.length(); i++){
        if (Character.isLowerCase(password.charAt(i)));
            LowerCount++;}
        if (LowerCount<3)
            Lower=false;
        else
            Lower=true;
    for(int i=0; i<password.length(); i++){
        if (Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i)));
            DigitCount++;}
        if (DigitCount<1)
            Digit=false;
        else
            Digit=true;
    if ((Digit == false) || (Upper == false) || (Lower == false))
        System.out.print("The password did not have enough of the following:");
    if (Upper == false)
        System.out.print("\nuppercase letters");
    if (Lower == false)
        System.out.print("\nlowercase letters");
    if (Digit ==false)
        System.out.print("\ndigits");
    if ((Digit==true)&&(Upper==true)&&(Lower==true))
        valid=true;

    }while(valid!=true);  
    System.out.println("Valid password");
```

I have been wrestling with it for a while now. Some problems I have had have been:

1. The counts not resetting to zero when returning to the top of the loop.
2. The loop not recognizing digits or putting completely wrong outputs based on my test runs.
3. Now it is just skipping the loop entirely and goes to the Valid Password statement no matter what I type into the input to test.

At this point I am really frustrated and could use some help.

Comment: Get rid of you semicolons `if (Character.isUpperCase(password.charAt(i)));`

Comment: Are you using an IDE? NetBeans and IntelliJ have code formatter, which would immediately show your if block isn't what you think it's doing. Try copy pasting your code  beautifier https://codebeautify.org/javaviewer if your IDE doesn't support it. And re-read your introductory text about if statements. Again, a proper IDE would usually have code snippets where you can easily type if blocks correctly with just a tab

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get rid of your semicolons. `if (Character.isUpperCase(password.charAt(i)));` should just be `if (Character.isUpperCase(password.charAt(i)))` and same for the other 2 if statements. Also, just as a sidenote for readability, I recommend moving your brackets to new lines so it's easier to see where your for loop ends. Originally I thought you had 3 if statements for each for loop but then I saw the bracket hidding in your first if statement

Comment: This worked! I don't know why I even put the semicolons on the if statements. Must've been getting tired or something. Deleted the semicolons, added some "\n" in to make the outputs look better. Had to change the input prompt to "Enter password: ", because the grader for the assignment was seeing the prompt when it looped back and saw it as an "Unexpected output" during the grading tests.

Answer (score -1):

Use below

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Main{

     public static void main(String []args){
       Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean valid= false;
    String password="";
   do{

    System.out.print("\nEnter a password that contains at least 2 uppercase letters, three lowercase letters, and at least 1 digit: ");
    password = inputDevice.nextLine();
    boolean Upper=false;
    boolean Lower=false;
    boolean Digit=false;
    int UpperCount=0;
    int LowerCount=0;
    int DigitCount=0;
    for(int i=0; i<password.length(); i++){
        if (Character.isUpperCase(password.charAt(i)))
            UpperCount++;
        else if(Character.isLowerCase(password.charAt(i)))
            LowerCount++;
        else if(Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i)))
            DigitCount++;
    }
     if (UpperCount>=2)
            Upper=true;
    if (LowerCount>=3)
            Lower=true;
    if (DigitCount>=1)
            Digit=true;

    if ((Digit == false) || (Upper == false) || (Lower == false))
        System.out.print("The password did not have enough of the following:");
    if (Upper == false)
        System.out.print("\nuppercase letters");
    if (Lower == false)
        System.out.print("\nlowercase letters");
    if (Digit ==false)
        System.out.print("\ndigits");
    if ((Digit==true)&&(Upper==true)&&(Lower==true))
        valid=true;

    }while(valid!=true);  
    System.out.println("Valid password");
     }
}
```

Comment: You can go further by using foreach instead of for, having a single variable instead of the long password.CharAt(i) will help readability. Also maybe assign the Upper, Lower and Digit directly, like Upper = UpperCount >=2;